# How to intercept http 302 response in Jersey Junit before it forwards to the 302 location URL

Tags: jersey, junit4

I'm banging my head to find a way to assert HTTP response code 302 using Junit framework in Jersey.

```
@Test
public void testResponseCodeWithNoIMEI() throws Exception {
    WebResource webResource = resource();
     ClientResponse clientResponse = webResource.path("/catalog").
                                        queryParam(RequestParams.PRODUCTCODE,"1234").
                                        queryParam(RequestParams.ID,"1234").                            
                                        header(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT,"Mozilla").
                                        header(HttpHeaders.IF_MODIFIED_SINCE,"Aug 2011").get(ClientResponse.class);
     LOG.debug("Server response :"+clientResponse);
```

This particular request should return me HTTP 302 +location. 
It is returning, but the ClientReqest is trying to navigate to that URL. I'm not sure about the default behaviour, but I want to stop and just check the HTTP 302 would be enough to make the test to pass. 
Basically it is one of the Junit test.

Any idea how to do this.

/Mohan

Comment: Since you acknowledge that there is a default behavior that you could look into - you may find it best to research that and update the question with what you've found. You may answer your own question, or provide enough for someone to have insight for you.  Don't presume everyone knows every default - do as much legwork as you can and bring it to the table... even if that is over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do

```
  com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client client = Client.create();
  client .setFollowRedirects(false);
```

It would be added to your `resource()` method.